# Excel Serial If statements

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm new to Excel, and I'm struggling with a formula. Essentially, what I'm looking for is to filter a cell through a set of procedures using a formula (this part isn't strict).

**For example**

Let's say I have a cell, `A1`. I'm trying to perform different calculations on this based on whether it is between a certain range of values. The problem is, it can be within several ranges.

*Pseudo-Code representation*

```
If(A1 > 187.5) {
   // Run some code here.
}

If(A1 > 150) {
   // Run some code here.
}
```

**NOTE** : The above example is only to illustrate the logic of sequential if statements.

Note that I **Do not** want a nested If statement. I'm just trying to run the same value through various checks. How do I do this in an Excel formula?

Comment: Do you want to "run code" in an excel formula? What's that?! Can you give an example of a "run code"?

Comment: No no. I'm just trying to illustrate the logic. I want sequential If statements, not nested if statements. I'm just struggling to find the appropriate syntax.

Comment: Maybe =(A1>187.5)*<some expression>+(A1>150)*<some expression>...?  Or the second term could be (A1>150)*(A1<=187.50)*..., if you are looking for mutually exclusive outcomes.

Comment: `=(A1 > 187.5) * <some expression>`. Will The boolean part of this be implicitly casted to a numeric value?

Comment: Yes (a fact which gets used in all sorts of tricky formulas).

Comment: Oooooooohh... Now that's interesting. I'll have a go with that. I think this might be the syntax I need. Do me a favor and turn your comment into an answer so I can mark it as correct if it works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can come up with is something like the following.

```
=(A1>187.5)*<some expression>+(A1>150)*<some expression>+....
```

The result of this will be some single value. (The straightforward way to get multiple values is to have the individual terms in separate cell.

If you want the result to reflect one among several mutually exclusive outcomes, then you would want to go with:

```
=(A1>187.5)*<some expression>+(A1>150)*(A1<=187.5)*...etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. One way is to use nested conditions like this:

`=IF(Something, do something, IF(something else, do something, do something))`

This is good if you want to condensate the formula a bit but arguably leads to more cluttered formulas. According to the FAST-Standard organization, those cases of nested conditions should be replaced by the use of flags. The most simple case would be, for example, where you would be looking for a rebate percentage according to a sales amount. In multiple cells you would have IF conditions evaluating to true only if the value matches that specific range. Then, your formula can be as simple as a SUMPRODUCT of your flags with your rebates percentages.

This is one example, but it can be applied to other cases very well too.

Comment: If you specify a bit more what you are trying to accomplish I could try to make my answer a bit more custom to your situation without removing the general advice part.

Comment: Well, this would be nested. So the second IF statement will ONLY execute if the first IF statement is False. I want the second If statement to execute anyway, regardless of the output of the first IF.

Comment: Then just make multiple IFs in the same formula. Again, how you do this is depending of what you are trying to achieve in the "Run some code here" sections.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a relationship between the numbers your checking for its very likely you can use

```
=CHOOSE(FLOOR(A1/160,1)+1,"<160",">160")
```

Which would put your 150 in the first and leave your 185 in the second